# bring the application from in focus, by clicking the icon of corresponding application

Tags: macos, qt

I was surprised this doesn't happen automatically, but I would like my applications window to be in focus as I click its dock icon, when in minimized mode.

Just to clarify, when I minimize the app, the window goes to dock, but when I click the its corresponding Dock Icon, the window don't come in focus.

Is there anything I am missing?

I am using Qt 4.5.3 on Mac OS X 10.5, 10.6

Thanks for help.
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First answer: That's the expected behavior of a Mac app. Try Safari for example. An app can be active without showing any window. In that case, only the menu bar at the top shows that the active app is changed. So, unless absolutely necessary, you shouldn't bring the minimized window back unless the user explicitly does so. That's the Mac way!

Second answer: I understand that there are cases where you want to bring the minimized window up. In Cocoa, the application delegate method  `-applicationDidBicomeActive` is called when the application gets the focus, and there you can bring the window up yourself. I'm sure Qt also has a similar event/callback/signal or whatever, but I don't know any Qt ... :p Sorry I can't be of any help.